# iptables port redirection wont work for localhost

Tags: iptables

I redirect port 80 to port 8000 via:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

The other host can access my webserver via 80 port, but the redirection cannot work in local host when I access 127.0.0.1:80.

Can port direction work for loopback network adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nat` table is used for [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), and is only used for external interfaces. You have to add the rule to a table that handles internal communication as well.

Comment: could you write what is the name of that internal table or how to define it?

Comment: @denu Use the normal `INPUT`/`OUTPUT` tables, with interface `lo` or ip-address `localhost`.

Comment: I found that using the two rules works for me.

`-t nat -A PREROUTING` and `-t nat -A OUTPUT`

see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170004/how-to-do-local-port-forwarding-with-iptables