# How to use ssh portforwarding correctly

Tags: unix, ssh, portforwarding

On my Pc i got a service which runs on port 51069. I want that this service is reachable with port 80.
I tried this comand

```
ssh -L 51069:localhost:80 localhost
```

But it not works, when i ask with my browser for localhost i get not the web service behind 51069.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46271/13377), or [this](https://superuser.com/a/591963/113356) will help.

Answer (score -1):

You have the ports the wrong way round. You want to forward traffic on port 80 to 51069 so it should be

```
ssh -L 80:localhost:51069 localhost
```

HOWEVER, you need root to be able to forward privileged ports (<= 1024) so you would have to ssh locally as root which might not be a great idea.

I'd personally use iptables for this: [How to do local port forwarding with iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170004/how-to-do-local-port-forwarding-with-iptables)